# JQgrid - onCellSelect does not trigger for cell editing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In JQgrid, if you want to do some pre-processing stuff before the cell of a table is edited ( the input is rendered on the DOM ). You can't do that, because for some reason the onCellSelect does not trigger at all. Reading the docs, it states that when doing inline cell editing, the onCellSelect event is disabled. Its kind of ambiguous, in the sense that the naming itself refers to cells being selected, so what's the reason to disable it ?

I've used the following properties to enable cell editing

```
   cellEdit : true,
   cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
   restoreCellonFail: true
```

Catching the cell selected event on

```
onCellSelect: (rowid, cellid, cellvalue) => {
   ....  do some stuff, like remove the formatter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which docs you read and which version is used, but you have two other ways to solve the problem.

1. In case you use formatter , you can use unformat to parse the format before editing.
2. the event beforeEditCell is more natural as name and is called just before editing

Comment: Hello Tony Tomov, I've tried the beforeEditCell event.The issue with that one is if, we try to remove the formatter from the input cell when editing. It only applies the changes after the cell is unselected or another cell is selected. Which in my case is not suitable as the formatter remains in the input

Comment: The version of jqgrid being used is 5.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, did find the answer, if you want to modify the cell content before the input is rendered, that is, for my case, to remove the formatter before editing. Just use the event formatCell like below. Worth mentioning in the doc like in red, because its not that obvious.

```
   formatCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
      let cell_value = value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
      return cell_value;
   }
```